# Efficiency of a chatbot

Tags: chatbot

For my graduation project I have to do research about defining the efficiency of our chatbot.

The chatbot asks the user to login before starting to chat to the bot. The way that the efficiency is defined at the moment is by deviding the answered questions by the total number of asked questions.

Now our main customer is complaining that the question about the login are also taken in consideration with the efficiency of the chatbot.

I was wondering if someone how to handle this. Is it correct to add the login questions to the efficiency or should is be taken out of consideration or weigh less heavy on the efficiency?

[An example of a conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eriAt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should not be considered.
Because it is a key phase where the chat bot start to interact with the user.
 What is the function of chat bot? -- it is to have a conversation with the users.

Suppose i will call you on the phone and say hello to start a conversation, will you consider hello as a conversation. it is just a phase or trigger to start conversation.

(This is just my opinion )
conclusion,  it is just a lamp rubbing action for genie to come out of the lamp. so do not consider the login phase/questions.

Comment: It is a conversational bot for a phone company that answers questions people have about their subscription or FAQs.

Comment: You use conversation question to login? It would be useful if u show some screenshot

Comment: I've added the image to the question

Comment: On replying "login" will it asks for username and password?

Comment: It redirects to the login page of the customer, and if the login is successful, the bot gets access to the data of the customer

Comment: Then it doesn't matter if u add it to the efficiency